# Calculate the limit of $\langle \partial_x f,\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B \rangle $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory, convolution

Let $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2\chi_E$ where $E=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x_1\geq 0 \}$ and let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $f$ is locally integrable, it can be interpreted as a distribution and I can take its distributional derivatives. I need to calculate
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \langle \partial_{x_1}f,\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B \rangle$$
where $\{\rho_{\varepsilon}\}$ are the standard mollifiers. Intuitively I think that this limit should be $0$. Here I present an approach that a friend of mine suggested.

**Attempt**

The answer would be clearly $0$ if $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2^2$ (I'll call this the "trivial version"). By the simmetry of the problem, the answer $A$ is the same if we replace $E$ with its complement. Clearly $2A$ is the answer to the trivial version (by additivity of the integral). And since $2A=0$, we have $A=0$.

This seems really nice, but is it correct? And is there a more direct approach?

Comment: We have $\partial_{x_1}f=x_2^2\delta(x_1)$ and $\rho_\varepsilon*\chi_B\to\chi_B$ so I expect the limit to equal $\int_{-1}^{1} x_2^2 \, dx_2.$ The integral limits $-1$ and $1$ here comes from the intersection of the line $x_1=0$ (because of $\delta(x_1)$) with $B.$

Comment: Why $\partial_{x_1}f=x_2^2\delta(x_1)$?

Comment: Notice that $\chi_E(x_1,x_2) = H(x_1),$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. Therefore,
$$\partial_{x_1} f = \partial_{x_1}(x_2^2\chi_E) = x_2^2 \partial_{x_1}\chi_E = x_2^2 \partial_{x_1}H(x_1) = x_2^2\delta(x_1).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of distributional derivatives, Fubini’s theorem, and the fundamental theorem of calculus, you have
\begin{align}
\langle \partial_{x_1}f,\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B \rangle=&-\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}x_2^2\chi_E\partial_{x_1}(\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B ) \,dx\\=&-\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_2^2\int_0^{\infty}\partial_{x_1}(\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B ) \,dx_1dx_2=\\&=-
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_2^2((\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B ) (\infty,x_2)-(\rho_\varepsilon \ast \chi_B )(0,x_2))\,dx_2
\end{align}
The mollification converges pointwise at every continuity point and the function has compact support. So you can use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to get that the limit is
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}0+x_2^2\chi_B  (0,x_2)\,dx_2$$

Comment: $\chi_B(0,x_2)$ can then be simplified to $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x_2)$.

Comment: yes, which gives exactly the result you wrote down